# PHPStorm Auto-complete Array Keys (dynamically inserted)

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, phpstorm, pimple

I'm using Pimple dependency injector, and every time I use a dependency from the container, I can't help but to double check the spelling of the key used to get the dependency:

```
$ioc = new Pimple();

// 1. Define some object
$ioc["some-key"] = $ioc->share(function($c){ /* ... */});

// 2. Use it
$ioc["som... // Open config file and check spelling...
```

**Does PHPStorm** have some way of looking up those properties and providing auto-completion? I have considered defining all those keys using something like

```
define('SOME_KEY', 'some-key');

// ...

$ioc[SOME_KEY] = $ioc->share(/* ... */);
```

but I wonder if there's a better way.

**Edit**

Here's some sample code:

```
// project_root/library/App/Injector/Ioc.php
require_once "Pimple.php";

/** @var array|Pimple $ioc */
$ioc = new Pimple();

$ioc["version"] = "1.0.1650.63";

$ioc["location-service"] = $ioc->share(function ($c) {
     return new Application_Service_Location();
   }
);
```

It turns out that string auto-completion works fine whether or not I include /** @var array|Pimple $ioc */ before the $ioc declaration **in the same file** as $ioc is declared. However, since I'm using Zend Framework, I'm usually using $ioc thusly:

```
// project_root/Application/Bootstrap.php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
   protected function _initInjector() {
     $ioc = null;
     require_once LIBRARY_PATH . "/MFM/Injector/ioc.php";
     Zend_Registry::set("ioc", $ioc);
   }
}

// project_root/Application/Controllers/SomeController.php
class Application_Controller_SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
   public function IndexAction() {
      /** @var Pimple $ioc */
      $ioc = Zend_Registry::get("ioc");

      // No IDE assistance for the string "location-service"
      $service = $ioc["location-service"];
   }
}
```

Comment: But ... PhpStorm has support for completing array keys, so it should work (depending on how you are using it, actually): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4353 . Maybe (just maybe -- have not tested this myself) it does not work because `$ioc` is not pure array but object with ArrayIterator (or similar) interface?

Comment: That's precisely why it doesn't work. PHPStorm even throws a warning (depending on intellisense settings) saying it can't follow dynamically added attributes.

Comment: So it's because of `ArrayAccess`.. OK. Currently PhpStorm has poor limited support for such stuff ( http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-937 ). Just an idea (not sure how it will work) -- what if you add typehint via PHPDoc stating that this variable is both plain array and instance of Pimple? e.g. `/** @var array|Pimple $ioc */` before `$ioc` initialisation.

Comment: Another tickets to watch after are: 1) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17116 and 2) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3423

Comment: In any case-- could you provide some simple code example that I could run few tests on it -- that's if above suggestion would not work, of course.

Comment: I'll try that. Currently I do use phpdoc to specify that $ioc is Pimple, which gives me intellisense on Pimple's methods. But since $ioc is created with 'new Pimple ()' that buys me little. It still won't analyze dynamic attributes (any I add through $ioc['attr_key']

Comment: @LazyOne just edited the question and added sample code

Comment: So .. `$ioc` is a local variable and not some class property defined only once. Yes, this would explain why it does not work as technically `$ioc` in one method/class is **different** to `$ioc` in another method/class. I **personally** do not think that anything can be done here ATM for array keys completion. Maybe when previously mentioned 2 tickets will be implemented (esp WI-17116) it could be possible to do something in this regard. I can only suggest to post your latest example with good description of required functionality as Feature Request ticket on the PhpStorm's Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently use the **DynamicReturnTypePlugin** for PhpStorm and have the following config of it in my `dynamicReturnTypeMeta.json`:

```
{
    "methodCalls": [
        {
            "class": "\\MyOwnWrapperOfDIContainer",
            "method": "get",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "class": "\\Pimple\\Container",
            "method": "offsetGet",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

This configurations means the following: whenever in code I'm using any variable of type `Pimple\Container` as an array (this will call its `ArrayAccess::offsetGet` method), then PhpStorm should consider the return value is of type that was used as a key when accessing that array. i. e.:

```
$c = new Pimple\Container;
$c['MyClass']->/*here autocompletion works*/methodOfMyClass();
```

I also use it in that way:

```
$myClassInstance = MyOwnWrapperOfDIContainer::get(MyClass::class);
$myClassInstance->methodOfMyClass(); // autocompletion works here
```

The only problem is when you register some dependencies in Pimple container not by their class name, but using other names which you want. E. g., autocompletion won't work in the following case:

```
$c = new Pimple\Container;
$c['my-favourite-var'] = new MyClass(1);
$c[MyClass::class] = new MyClass(2);
$c['my-favourite-var']->/*here autocompletion doesn't work*/methodOfMyClass();
$c['MyClass']->/*here autocompletion works*/methodOfMyClass();
```

Still you can workaround it like this:

```
class MyFavouriteVar extends MyClass;
$c[MyFavouriteVar::class] = new MyFavouriteVar(2);
// or even like this:
$c[MyFavouriteVar::class] = new MyClass(2);
$c[MyFavouriteVar::class]->/*now autocompletion works fine*/methodOfMyClass();
```

Or you have to find some other solution of your problem...

## edit 1

also consider this article:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

## edit 2

and this plugin
https://github.com/Sorien/silex-idea-plugin

## edit 3

Also it's possible to workaround the problem mentioned above like this:

```
class MyPimple extends Pimple\Container
{
    public function get($type, $desc = null) {
        return $this[$type . (isset($desc) ? ':' . $desc : '')];
    }
}
$c = new MyPimple;
$c[MyClass::class] = new MyClass('default');
$c[MyClass::class . ':' . 'my-special-value'] = new MyClass('special');
$c->get(MyClass::class, 'my-special-value')->/*autocompletion should work*/methodOfMyClass();
```

The `dynamicReturnTypeMeta.json` should then contain:

```
{
    "methodCalls": [
        {
            "class": "\\MyPimple",
            "method": "get",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the file ".phpstorm.meta.php" into root of your repository. Content of file .phpstorm.meta.php:

```
<?php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override( \Container::get(0), map([]));
}
```

Where \Container::get - method for get some object, example:

```
\Container::get('My\Super')
```

or

```
\Container::get(My\Super::class)
```

and now you can use autocomplete of all class methods.